# How can we be safe from hitting a glass wall that is hard to notice?

Tags: physical, human-eye

This picture was taken in a Korea airport. I found it very hard to notice many glass partitions, including this one. I almost hit once.

[image: Picture of a glass door in a Korean airport]

**What will be the approach to get away from this kind of accident so we can live longer?**

Answer (score 3):

It is a common approach to **use some kind of serigraphy** (kind of sticker) in the glass so we can see through but notice there is a surface.

You can also play with the values of **reflection and refraction** of the material. Not only in the material but in the way the space is designed. So there can be lights (or lighter space like an exterior) behind the user and darker space behind the glass that make it more visible. Or even the disposition of the glass surface with regard of the user to create those extra reflections.

Other than that a correct design that doesn't make conflicts in the way the user enters spaces through such glass doors. When the glass separates two spaces (a window) making it clear that there is no continuity between the interior and exterior space can help (for example using a different pavement or a change of height between the spaces).

Comment: The movie "Spanglish" has a scene of someone smacking in to a glass door that was essentially invisible, only the occupants of the house knew it was there. I frequently use the phrase "hit a glass wall", meaning that I have encountered a conundrum that I hadn't seen coming.

Comment: Having watched a small child go runnning into a glass door - it's also important to have the 'kind of sticker' at child height as well as adult height.